# Can I create hyperlinks to navigate inside Visual Studio files?

Tags: visual-studio, hyperlink

At design time it can be helpful to jump back in code to a caller and vice versa especially when many files and windows are already open.

How can I create hyperlinks in my code or comments to navigate inside Visual Studio files?
e.g. like this:

```
// vs://CallingClassName.cs#methodeName()
// some further comments
Class AService1 {
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have VS 2015, you can do it without any add-ins. I think it didn't work in earlier versions of VS. Just use standard XML doc comments with link elements: <see> or <seealso>. Here's an example with multiple ways for creating a link:

```
/// <summary>
/// My class description.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// See <see cref="CallingClassName.methodeName"/> for further details.
/// </remarks>
/// <seealso cref="CallingClassName.methodeName"/>
/// <seealso cref="CallingClassName.methodeName">A method with further details.</seealso>
Class AService1 {
}
```

If you just want to place a single link without any additional comments, I would prefer the <seealso> tag because it's a top level XML comment tag and it doesn't require a parent, such as <summary> or <remarks>.

Then just right click on the cref value and select "Go To Definition" or press F12. You will be navigated to the correct code element.

As a bonus, when you use XML comments, you'll get IntelliSense description and you can generate the class documentation with [VSdocman](http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html) (our product) or Sandcastle.